# How to set a button's command to run on itself, when the buttons are stored in a list?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am running a loop which adds `Tkinter` buttons to a list. I want to make each button have a command that runs based on the particular button that was clicked - for now - toggling the relief between `raised` and `sunken`.
I can't get the command to run on the specific button, it always runs on the last button in the list of buttons, regardless of which button I actually click on.

I tried manually setting the command for each button without a loop (but still with a list!), which worked, but I need to use a loop.

I also tried creating a second loop after the first one.

```py
def toggle_button(self):
    if self['relief'] == 'raised':
        self['relief'] = 'sunken'
    elif self['relief'] == 'sunken':
        self['relief'] = 'raised'
for event in list_of_data:
    event_buttons.append(Button(popup, text=event['event name'], relief='raised'))
    event_buttons[-1].pack()
# Approach 1
    event_buttons[-1].config(command=lambda: toggle_button(event_buttons[-1]))
```

Approach 2:

```py
for button in event_buttons:
    button.config(command=lambda: toggle_button(button))
```

I expect `event_buttons[0]['command']` to be

```
lambda: toggle_button(event_buttons[0])
event_buttons[1]['command'] = lambda: toggle_button(event_buttons[1])
event_buttons[2]['command'] = lambda: toggle_button(event_buttons[2])
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to pass the actual button as an argument for lambda:

```
event_buttons[-1].config(command=lambda button = event_buttons[-1] : toggle_button( button ))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you!